Kids TV where the main character gets powers and wears a red outift with boxing gloves
I’m looking for a show that was aired in mid 2000.
There is a kid/teen who gets powers, (not sure how, but I think he found a robot that gave him his power and that is a maybe) but anyways, the kid turns all red, red outfit red mask and red boxing gloves, it has the same vibe as Eon kid/Iron kid because it’s CGI/3D and the main character fights a robot bull.
In one episode he fights a group of people for a box that they don’t have any idea what is inside of it, but it turns out to be just a TV antenna.
And after the fight with the bull the main villain creates a new robot that looks like a skeleton.
